# How to filter on 2 attributes at once with Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following models:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    item_involved = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through=ItemInvolved)


class ItemInvolved(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='item_involvement')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    kind = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I want to retrieve all `Parent`s for which an `Item` has pk=20 and its `ItemInvolved` has kind=10.

Edit:

Say I have the following objects:

```
Parent(pk=1)
Parent(pk=2)
Parent(pk=3)
ItemInvolved(pk=11, parent=1, item=18, kind=10)
ItemInvolved(pk=12, parent=1, item=19, kind=10)
ItemInvolved(pk=13, parent=1, item=20, kind=10)
ItemInvolved(pk=14, parent=2, item=20, kind=10)
ItemInvolved(pk=15, parent=3, item=19, kind=10)
ItemInvolved(pk=16, parent=3, item=20, kind=20)
```

I need a query that will yield:

```
[<Parent: 1>, <Parent: 2>]
```

Comment: If any of the below answers helped you, then it's a good practice to accept one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>`parents = Parent.objects.filter(item=20, item__kind=10)`</del>

OK. Got it.

```
parents = Parent.objects.filter(item_involved=20, item_involvement__kind=10)
```

Further explanation on [spanning multi valued relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

Comment: This doesn't do what I want. This filters `Parent` by its own `pk`.

Comment: I mistakenly accepted an edit which changed this. Sorry. Thanks for pointing it out! I just have changed it.

Comment: Added content to clarify what I'm trying to achieve. Also `item__kind` (or rather `item_involved__kind`, I changed the name) shouldn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer (once again!)

Comment: Can't use `item_involved__kind`. `item_involved` doesn't carry `kind` it's a related field.

Comment: Its `item_involvement` not `item_involved`!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships greatly helped me understand why your filter worked. Consider adding it in your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to log an exception, if the corresponding query is not successful:

`try:
     parent = Parent.objects.get(item=20, item__kind=10)
except Exception as e:
     print "[CRITICAL] <some_view.py> - {}".format(e)`